# How to fix 401 Unauthorized issue in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

```
Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start: 2019-02-08 15:51:46 IST
Load time: 1412
Connect Time: 525
Latency: 1412
Size in bytes: 1508
Sent bytes:603
Headers size in bytes: 843
Body size in bytes: 665
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
Response code: 401
Response message: Unauthorized
```

Response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Public-Key-Pins-Report-Only: pin-sha256="9n0izTnSRF+W4W4JTq51avSXkWhQB8duS2bxVLfzXsY="; pin-sha256="5kJvNEMw0KjrCAu7eXY5HZdvyCS13BbA0VJG1RSP91w="; pin-sha256="njN4rRG+22dNXAi+yb8e3UMypgzPUPHlv4+foULwl1g="; max-age=86400; includeSubDomains; report-uri="https://a.forcesslreports.com/hpkp-report/00Dq0000000DFMbm";
Expect-CT: max-age=0; report-uri="https://a.forcesslreports.com/Expect-CT-report/00Dq0000000DFMbm";
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests
Referrer-Policy: origin-when-cross-origin
Cache-Control: no-cache,must-revalidate,max-age=0,no-store,private
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
X-Powered-By: Salesforce.com ApexPages
P3P: CP="CUR OTR STA"
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Comment: Add a cookiemanager to your script and authenticate in a request..

Answer (score 1):

Looking into [JMeter – Logging Into Salesforce for Automated Testing](http://blog.deadlypenguin.com/blog/2017/06/29/jmeter-logging-salesforce/) article you need to extract `session id` dynamic parameter from the very first request (Log In). The process is known as [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start)

The Session ID parameter can be extracted using [XPath Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0), the relevant configuration would be something like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The server rejects the request with a “401 Unauthorized” error because your app needs to be authorized. Usually Authentication request returns this value. So, you need to extract this token from the answer.

1. Add [Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan.
2. Add [Regular Expressions Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) to your auth request to [Extract auth token to variable](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2018/09/jmeter-extract-and-re-use-as-variable/) and send its value to the next request (where you get error) with

This guide also could be helpful [how to test authentification with JMeter](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2018/05/test-rest-apis-authentication-using-jmeter/)